# xgboost Gini Feature Importance - standardized data vs raw data

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost

I have an XGBoost model and the Gini feature importance that I get if I pass in standardized data vs non-standardized data is completely different. I thought xgboost is immune to standardization. Can you please help me understand?

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  def train_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    xg = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=350, subsample=1.0, scale_pos_weight=25, min_child_weight=8, max_depth=21,
                                    learning_rate=0.1, gamma=0.2, colsample_bytree=0.5)
        xg.fit(x_train, y_train)
        return xg

def find_feat_imp(model, cols):
    feat_importance = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=cols)
    sort_feat_imp = feat_importance.sort_values(ascending=False)
    sort_feat_imp
        sort_feat_imp[:20].plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test  = read_data()
xg = train_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
find_feat_imp(xg,x_train.columns)
```

The output of standardized data is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6sW0.png) and the output of raw data is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/If5u8.png)

The important features are completely different. Can you please help me understand?

I was expecting the feature importance to be the same since xgboost is not affected by standardizing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a random seed, so the models may be different just due to random chance.  In particular, because you set `colsample_bytree<1`, you get a random effect in which columns are available per tree.  Since the first trees are usually the most impactful, if a feature happens to be left out of them, its importance score will suffer.  (Note however that xgboost supports several feature importance types; this effect might be more or less noticeable depending on which type you are using.)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I set colsample < 1 so as to avoid overfitting. To get the feature importance, is it advisable to set it as 1?

Comment: Feature importances from xgboost will tell you how important the features are to _that particular, fitted, model_.  In that capacity, it doesn't matter.  If you want to infer something about importance to the real world data model, then maybe it's better to increase colsample, or to reduce learning rate and increase number of trees, but it's hard to say.  Maybe try stats.SE with that question?

Answer (score -1):

XGBoost, like many other tree-based models, is not affected by feature scaling because the algorithm splits the data based on the values of the features, rather than using the scale of the features. However, the feature importance scores generated by XGBoost can be affected by feature scaling because they are based on the feature's contribution to the reduction of the impurity criterion (e.g. Gini impurity) at each split. Standardizing the data can change the relative scale of the features, which in turn can change their relative importance as determined by the impurity reduction criterion. Therefore, it is recommended to use the same data preprocessing method when comparing feature importance values.

Comment: This is incorrect, I think.  The reduction in impurity doesn't care about feature values either, just the gini impurity of the parent and child nodes, which in turn is only about the proportion of classes in those nodes.  (Also xgboost supports more than just gini impurity improvements as feature importances.)